# How to add a working link to external css file in .NET core 5 project

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-5.0

My project is [here](https://github.com/haimHadad/HFD-Covid19.git)

**(Look for "Laptop" branch, and "IsolatorUI" internal project)**

I need to work with external css file I just saved in **wwwroot/css.**
I have a schtml Home view file and I would like to use it there.
So far, everything I tried did not work. Even using the site.css which was already there was unsuccessful.

Please ignore the different languague on cshtml HomeView file.

How can I establish a css file link? There are many discussions and suggestions I found on the internet, but none of them worked for me.

It's really frustrating when such simple thing doesn`t work...

Comment: What is your problem? Hasn't the Index View under your Home successfully applied wwwroot/css/site.css?

Comment: In your view:`@section Scripts{  <script src="~/css/your css"></script>}`

Comment: @ Yinqiu: I tried, and it not working (site.css)

Comment: Your “site.css” is quoted in the layout by default. All your pages will contain the css. You can delete the reference in your layout and you can see the difference.

Comment: I can't lie I was looking for this same information and you right most answers are like 10 years old a whole other version and it did not work here

Answer (score 1):

Basically there is a disturbing bug with css in .NET framework  files, but eventually this code worked for me:

In my View:

```
@section Styles {
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/css/Home.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}
```

And in my Layout:

```
<head>
     ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/site.css" />
    @RenderSection("Styles", false)
</head>
```

Comment: So is the same if I wanted to just make my css to work just in that specific view? I looked something up and to no avail but it was talking asp.net6 I am using 5.